# Set Browser Title for PDF Page

Tags: javascript, html, browser, code-generation

I load a pdf that the user clicks on via a URL call. See the following javascript:

```
$("ul.card[data-entry-id]").css("cursor","pointer").on("click",
    function(event)
    {
        document.location = "/archives/entry/" + $(this).attr("data-entry-id");
    }
);
```

I want to change the browser title of the pdf that comes up, so that it is not just the url. Adding `document.title("New Title")` to the function block does not work because it is not synchronized with the server returning the file that's being displayed in the browser. How can I overcome this?

Perhaps I could open a new page (rather than changing the document location) that wraps the URL call in html so that I can set the title - something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="/archives/entry/98"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

And that way, I could set the title. How can I write this html to a new page from within the javascript function block I have that responds to a click? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, changing the documents location ***does*** open a new page, so anything you do in the current page after the call to document.location has no effect, as a new page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing location you can load data by ajax.

```
$("ul.card[data-entry-id]").css("cursor","pointer").on("click",
    function(event)
    {
        var title = $(this).text();
        var url = "/archives/entry/" + $(this).attr("data-entry-id");
        document.body.innerHTML = "<p>Loading...</p>"; // Or a loading image

        $.ajax(url).done(function(data){
            $(document.body).html(data);
            document.title = title;
        })
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set a title in the PDF document you can make it display as your browser title.

Follow these instructions:

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with a large batch of pdfs that don't already have titles set.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery approach, relatively easy to modify for plain JavaScript:

```
$('body').html('<iframe src="/archives/entry/98">');
document.title = "New Title";
```